# Jquery tools: Rangeinput get value on input change

Tags: jquery, range, jquery-tools

I use [**Jquery tools rangeinput**](http://flowplayer.org/tools/rangeinput/).

For example I have:

```
  <input id="testId" title="test" class="range" type="range" name="test" min="0" max="3000" value="15" />
```

And script:

```
$(".range").rangeinput();

        $("#testId").live('change', function() { 
            console.log($(this).data("rangeinput").getValue());    
        });
```

So by default my value is 15. Then I type in my input 25, but result in console is 15, than I type 20, but result is 25. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: May be you are trying the read it before the plugin updates its value that is why you are always getting the last value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way instead. What's happening is the changed value isn't set before you call getValue. Calling `setTimeout` of `0` will fix that.

```
$(".range").rangeinput();

$(".range").live('change', function(){
    var $range = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log($range.data('rangeinput').getValue());
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: I think that ".live" is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get rid of `live` and directly use `change` it will work because plugin uses the change event itself.

```
 $("#testId").change(function() { 
      console.log($(this).data("rangeinput").getValue());    
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span>Totar horizontalmente</span>
<input id="rota_hor" type='range' name='range' min='0' max='360' step='10' value='3' style="width: 350px;"/>

<script>
    $("#rota_hor").change(function()
    { 
        console.log($(this).attr("value"));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use  [jQuery Tools scripting](http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/scripting.html#api) data(toolname) [API](http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/rangeinput/index.html#api) for access to values

```
<input id="myRange" name="some_name" type="range" value="20" min="0" max="100" step="10" />

<script>
var rangeApi = $('#myRange').rangeinput({
    // Some settings here if it needed
}).data('rangeinput');
rangeApi.setValue(100);
console.log(rangeApi.getValue());
</script>
```