# Adding slider values together

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two JQ Mobile sliders: slide1 and slide2 and Im using localStorage to hold their values between pages after a next button is clicked(#save and #save2). I want to add their values on the third page. Everything is working as it should except for adding the two values together. Here is my script:

```
<script>

    $("#save").click(function(){
        var slide1 = $("#slide1").val();
        localStorage.slide1 = slide1;

    });
    $("#save2").click(function(){
        var slide2 = $("#slide2").val();
        localStorage.slide2 = slide2;     
    });

    $(document).on('pagebeforechange', function(){
    numSlide1 = parseInt(localStorage.slide1);
    numSlide2 = parseInt(localStorage.slide2);
    var sumTotal = numSlide1 + numSlide2;
    $('.total').val(sumTotal);
    });
</script>
```

I seem to be having an issue with this specifically: $('.total').val(sumTotal);

Comment: so if you run `alert(sumTotal);` before trying to set the value you get a pop-up with the correct number?

Comment: Actually, I cannot get it to run at all with $('.total').val(sumTotal); uncommented.

Comment: So if you comment out that last line, and try to run an alert on the sumTotal, does it return the correct number? Also, can you share your markup and any console errors you get?

Comment: Yes it does return the correct number when I add alert(sumTotal). I just need the number to show up in the selector (.total) because Ill be adding other values as I create more pages.

Comment: So can you share your HTML as well?

Comment: Save values on `pagehide` or `pagebeforehide` then on `pagebeforeshow` update `.total` value. Make sure to specify page id on those events.

Answer (score 0):

From my research looks like it could be an issue with the value not being captured when you first make the click. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9180358/1935338) may work. Alternatively, it may work if you change .click to .vclick in JQ mobile.